# Do you need to close streams?

Tags: java, syntax, inputstream

This question comes in two parts:

**What is the difference between `InputStream i1 = new InputStream()` and `new InputStream()`?**
and
**Is it worth it to create all local variables just to close them?**

I know the simple answers with the first you can keep the variable, continue to use the variable and even close the input stream like a good programmer. The second you have lost its reference, but it looks more concise. Is there any memory difference between the two? How about speed difference (in destruction)?

Now to the examples that spurred my thoughts. First we use `'new Object()` with no regards to throwing it away.

```
 public void getLongStrings() throws IOException {
        try {
            foo = FileCopyUtils.copyToString(new InputStreamReader(aBook.getInputStream()));
            bar = FileCopyUtils.copyToString(new InputStreamReader(aNovel.getInputStream()));
        }
        catch (IOException ioe) {
            //do something appropriate here;
        }
    }
```

Now for the more verbose method

```
public void getLongStrings() throws IOException {
        InputStream i1 = null;
        InputStream i2 = null;
        InputStreamReader isr1 = null;
        InputStreamReader isr2 = null;
        try {
            i1 = aBook.getInputStream();
            i2 = aNovel.getInputStream();
            isr1 = new InputStreamReader(i1);
            isr2 = new InputStreamReader(i2);
            foo = FileCopyUtils.copyToString(isr1);
            bar = FileCopyUtils.copyToString(isr2);
        }
        catch (IOException ioe) {
            //do something appropriate here
        } finally {
            if (i1 != null) i1.close();
            if (i2 != null) i2.close();
            if (isr1 != null) isr1.close();
            if (isr2 != null) isr2.close();
        }
    }
```

Is the first or second better? Is one faster over the other? Is it smart to close all of my streams even though it doesn't look at pretty?

Thanks for any insights (or edits).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The second you have lost its reference, but it looks more concise.

Yes, it is more concise. You're doing less with the object - importantly, you're not doing things you *should* be doing. Taking a shortcut will often produce less code, but by leaving file handles open pending the finalizer closing things, you'll find that you'll get exceptions which are hard to reproduce reliably.

> Is there any memory difference between the two?

Maybe, but that's not relevant. The important resource here isn't the memory, but the file handle.

> How about speed difference (in destruction)?

Again, likely to be irrelevant. Correctness is far more important.

(Note that your current second code is still not completely reliable - if one of the early `close()` calls throws an exception, you won't close the rest.)

If you're using Java 7, you should look at the [try-with-resources statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html), which makes all of this a lot simpler.

EDIT: As noted in JB Nizet's answer, the code you're using *may* already close the underlying stream - it depends on what `FileCopyUtils` is. If it's the Spring class, you're okay. If it's something else, you may not be. You should read the documentation. The general principle is as above though: you should make sure that *something* closes the streams. Don't assume that just because *in this case* you don't need to close things explicitly, that that's true in the general case.

Note that [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com)'s [`InputSupplier`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/io/InputSupplier.html) and [`OutputSupplier`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/io/OutputSupplier.html) interfaces are useful here - it allows you to pass around the suppliers knowing that the input/output haven't been opened *yet*... which means that other code can perform the open/copy/close (or whatever is required) and handle it all for you... you don't end up using any objects in your code which *could* be closed.

Comment: @JBNizet: It's correct *if* it's using code which auto-closes. But you're making an assumption there, and the OP needs to be aware that the streams *should be closed*, whoever closes it. Will edit though.

Comment: Isn't it what I said in my answer?

Comment: @JBNizet: Yes, but it's not what you said in the comment. The unconditional statement of "Actually, the first snippet is correct" is an overstatement based on an assumption, and could easily lead the OP into a false sense of security. See my edit, which talks about that and the Guava approach.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming this is Spring's FileCopyUtils, [its javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/FileCopyUtils.html#copyToString%28java.io.Reader%29) says:

> All copy methods use a block size of 4096 bytes, **and close all affected streams when done**.

(emphasis mine)

So your inital approach is perfectly fine in this case: Spring handles the closing of the Reader, and closing a Reader closes the wrapped stream.

If that wasn't the case, you would have to close the Reader, preferrably using Java 7's *try with resources*.

Note that your second example, closes the stream but doesn't have to: closing the reader automatically closes it. Also note that if the first reader can't be closed and throws an IOException, the second won't be closed correctly. Another good reason to use *try with resources*, whic is guaranteed to close everything.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `FileCopyUtils.copyToString()` **does not** close the provided stream then the second approach is better.

`close()` has to be called to release any resources associated with the stream. So it is not a matter of code prettiness or performance, but correctness.

The second approach has a bug, when any of the `close` calls throws an exception all the remaining `close()` calls will not be invoked.

Comment: As mentioned by Jon Skeet, the second approach isn't really correct. And as noted by me, the first one is in fact correct. See my answer.

Comment: @JBNizet agreed that is why there is "more correct (although not completely)", but ok, correctness is binary, correct or not correct so I will update the answer.